Tex Studio, arxiv and Biber
I've been struggling to upload my article to arxiv that I created in TeX Studio, but it seems impossible since arxiv yields the error

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: (biblatex) article
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

I am aware that using this commands in the preamble
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, hyperref,backref,backrefstyle=none,style=numeric-comp, sorting=none,maxbibnames=5,url=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage = {cited on page},%
    backrefpages = {cited on pages}%
}
\addbibresource{article.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \hfil\penalty90\hfilneg\space DOI\addcolon\addnbspace
    \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

may create some problems, but I'm not being able to obtain a solution, although that I read many references, e.g., this or this. Before ending the document, I'm writing \printbibliography and everything works fine! Tex Studio works fine, but arxiv don't. It's been many hours in trying to solve this.
--
EDIT: I put the log and messages:
Log:
777: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for thisparticular \caption
1086: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `math shift'
1086: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `\xi'
1086: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `math shift'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `math shift'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `superscript'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `subscript'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `superscript'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `subscript'
1117: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):removing `math shift'
1224: Overfull \hbox (18.61806pt too wide) in paragraph
1224: Overfull \hbox (115.69435pt too wide) in paragraph
1224: Overfull \hbox (5.3904pt too wide) in paragraph
1224: Overfull \hbox (92.54893pt too wide) in paragraph
: name{Hfootnote.8} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
: name{Hfootnote.3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
: name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
: name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Messages:
Process started: bibtex.exe "article"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 24.4)
The top-level auxiliary file: article.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file article.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file article.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file article.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)


Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "article".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: biber.exe "article"

INFO - This is Biber 2.20
INFO - Logfile is 'article.blg'
INFO - Reading 'article.bcf'
INFO - Found 67 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'article.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'article.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'article.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to article.bbl
WARN - Duplicate entry key: 'Anastasiou:2022wjq' in file 'article.bib', skipping ...
WARN - legacy month field 'Sep' in entry 'kerr' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Dec' in entry 'israel' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'May' in entry 'heusler' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Apr' in entry 'janis' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Apr' in entry 'Deffayet1' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Sep' in entry 'Deffayet2' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Nov' in entry 'MaselliBHs' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'Dec' in entry 'Brihaye2009' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - legacy month field 'May' in entry 'PhysRevD.15.2752' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
INFO - WARNINGS: 10

Process exited normally



Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "article".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "article".tex

Process exited normally


You need to create the bbl locally and upload together with your file. And you need to ensure that the bbl has been created with the same version of biblatex then the one of arxiv, which is something from texlive 2023 see https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html#biblatex

I don't understand: What do you mean with "You need to create the bbl locally"? If that means using my laptopt, yep, I'm doing it with TeXstudio, in the sense that I have a .bib file that I compile and automatically produce a .bbl file.

(Worth to say that I am compiling with LaTeX -> Biber -> LaTeX -> PdfLaTeX -> Internal PdF Viewer, in Texstudio, and in that temporal order.)

and this bbl you have to upload to arxiv so that they can use it.

@UlrikeFischer, I did it. I uploaded just the .bbl and .tex but arXiv does not compile it according to the error I put.

did you ensure that the bbl has the right version? What does the full log says?

I added the log and messages as an edit, above.

oh come on. Think a bit. The problem is on arxiv so you need the log-files from there - and I doubt very much that it will use miktex. In any case: biber 2.20 is to new. You need a bbl created with biber 2.19 and (probably) biblatex  2023/03/05 v3.19 vor arxiv.

Hey, easy. I've been trying a lot and reading. It's not that I did the lazy job. Is just that I'm pedestrian in these things.

in the local log you did show, why are you running bibtex when you have specified (the default) biber to be used.

A thing that seems to work for folks in this situation is to load their project into Overleaf and select the TeX Live 2023 instance that they're running and compile it there, and download the bbl file from overleaf when submitting to arXiv. Just make sure that you're uploading the file with the correct name.

(as an aside, we've been seeing this a lot lately, and the general recommendation is to not use biber with arXiv and newer tl instances. If I was a betting man, sometime next year we'll likely be in TL 2024, and running a much less nuanced version of tex live)
